# Defining the database schema in the application or in the database?

Tags: database, orm, schema

I know that the title might sound a little contradictory, but what I'm asking is with regards to ORM frameworks (SQLAlchemy in this case, but I suppose this would apply to any of them) that allow you to define your schema within your application.

Is it better to change the database schema directly and then update the column types in your program manually, or does it make more sense to define the tables in your application and then use the ORM framework's table generation functions to make the schema and then build the tables on the database side for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal belief is that you should design the database on its own merits. The database is the best place to handle things modeling your Domain data. The database is also the biggest source of slow down in applications and letting your ORM design your database seems like a bad idea to me. :)

Of course, I've only got a couple of big projects behind me. I'm still learning daily. :)

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that applications and databases tend to live in a M:M relationship in any but the most trivial cases.  If your application is at all likely to have interfaces to other systems, reports, data extracts or loads, or data migrated onto or off it from another system then the database has *more than one stakeholder.*

Be nice to the other stakeholders in your application.  Take the time and get the schema right and put some thought into data quality in the design of your application.  Keep an eye on anyone else using the application and make sure you don't break bits of the schema that they depend on without telling them.  This means that the database has a life of its own to a greater or lesser extent.  The more integration, the more independent the database.

Of course, if nobody else uses or cares about the data, feel free to ignore my advice.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to define your database schema is to start with modeling your application domain (domain driven design anyone?) and seeing what tables take shape based on the domain objects you define.

I think this is the best way because really the database is simply a place to persist information from the application, it should never lead the design.  It's not the only place to persist information as well.  We have users that want to work from flat files or the database for instance.  They could also use XML files.  So by starting with your domain objects and then generating tables (or flat file or XML schema or whatever) from there will lead to a much better design in the end.

While this may depend on you using an object-oriented language, using an ORM tool like Hibernate/NHibernate, SubSonic, etc. can really make this transition easy for you up to, and including generating the database creation scripts.

In reference to performance, performance should be one of the last things you look at in an application, it should never drive the design.  After you get a good schema up and running based on your domain you can always make tweaks to improve its performance.

Answer (score 1):

Alot depends on your skill level with the specific database product that you're going to use.  Think of it as the difference between a "manual" and "automatic" transmission car.  ORMs provide you with that "automatic" transmission, just start designing your classes, and let the ORM worry about getting it stored into the database somehow.

Sounds good. The problem with most ORMs is that in their quest to be PI "persistence ignorant", they often don't take advantage of specific database features that can provide elegant solutions for a given task.  Notice, I didn't say ALL ORMs, just most.

My take is to design the conceptual data model first yourself.  Then you can go in either direction, up towards the application space, or down towards the physical database.  But remember, only YOU know if it's more advantageous to use a view instead of a table, should you normalize or de-normalize a table, what non-clustered index(es) make sense with this table, is a natural or surrogate key more appropriate for this table, etc...  Of course, if you feel that these questions are beyond your grasp, then let the ORM help you out.

One more thing, you really need to seperate the application design from the database design.  They are almost never the same.  How important is that data?  Could another application be designed to use that data?  It's a lot easier to refactor an application than it is to refactor a database with a billion rows of data spread across thousands of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can get away with it, doing it in the application is probably the best way.  Since it's a perfect example of the DRY principle.

Having said that however, getting away with it is always going to be hard to pull off since you're practically choosing to give up most database specific optimizations.  (more so, with querying, but it still applies to schemas (indexes, etc)).

You'll probably end up changing the schema by hand anyway, and then you'll be stuck with a brittle database schema that's going to be the source of your worst nightmares :)

My 2 Cents

Answer (score 0):

Design each based on their own requirements as much as possible. Trying to keep them in too rigid sync is a good illustration of increased coupling/decreased cohesion.

Come to think of it, ORMs can easily be used to spread coupling (even though it can be avoided to some degree).